# Can adding black scanline video reduce video size?

Tags: video, compression

Scanline effect refers to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scan_line

I have thought of a new way to reduce video size by half, by adding black scanline every 2 row of pixel, the video as a whole will look darker from a far but will the size effectively got reduced by 2 times because we removed half of the information?

What I am wondering is are there any compression technique based on this idea or similar, since I think there must be someone who have thought of this before.

Comment: That is not how video compression works. You may find the size actually goes *up*, because you're breaking up what were previously contiguous blocks in the frame.

Comment: I mean, the data in the video file will not have the black scanline at all. It is as if you removed every even row and move all the odd rows tightly together (result in halved height) and then compress that in any algorithm. On render, every row will get stretched out and added black scanline to fill the gap.